# How do I solve this error message when overloading the << operator

Tags: c++

when I try to overload the << operator I get the error "too many parameters for this operator function"?

This is the code I have written:

```
class studentrecord{
string firstname, lastname, grade;        
studentrecord(string firstname, string lastname, string grade){
    this -> firstname = firstname;
    this -> lastname = lastname;
    this -> grade = grade;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const studentrecord& studentrecord) {
    os << "\n\t" << studentrecord.firstname << "\t" << studentrecord.lastname << "\t" << studentrecord.grade;
    return os;
}
};
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you may need a `friend`

Comment: Ahh yes! Thank you @DesmondGold

Comment: [Queue the music!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaZpZQG2z10)

Answer (score 3):

@DesmondGold pointed out the answer, just use the "friend" keyword.

The proper use of this function can be seen on this page:

[Overloading the << Operator for Your Own Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=msvc-160)

The code becomes:

```
class studentrecord{
string firstname, lastname, grade;        
studentrecord(string firstname, string lastname, string grade){
    this -> firstname = firstname;
    this -> lastname = lastname;
    this -> grade = grade;
}

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const studentrecord& studentrecord) {
    os << "\n\t" << studentrecord.firstname << "\t" << studentrecord.lastname << "\t" << studentrecord.grade;
    return os;
}
};
```